# extjs actioncolumn renderer prevents handler

Tags: c#, extjs

I have a actioncolumn on my grid with this code:

```
    this.columns =
    [
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            items: [{
                icon: '../Content/Images/Approve.png',
                handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, node, e, record, rowNode) {
                    alert('test approve')
                }
            }
          ...rest of the columns
```

when I click the icon, I get the "test approve" message, so it works as expected!

If I add the render method bellow to disable the action column for rows that are already approved:

```
            renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                if (record.get('Approved') = 1) {                        
                    this.items[0].disabled = true
                } else {
                    this.items[0].disabled = false;                       
                }
            }
```

the `handler` stops working on the enabled itens. It seems like the `renderer` function is preventing the `handler` to be called. I even tried to add the `handler` code inside the `renderer`, but also no success.

Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 3):

your condition statement in the if statement, i assume you meant to compare not assign. thats probably where your code is breaking

Comment: delete this answer, please.

Comment: Why should it be deleted? It's a valid point, there is a `=` instead of `==` or `===` in the `if` condition, there is no way that condition should work as expected.