# prevent a checkbox from being clicked or displayed

Tags: c#, extjs

can I prevent a checkbox on a grid cell from being clicked?

this is my column:

```
{
    header: 'Select',
    dataIndex: 'indexSelect',
    width: 75,
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    renderer: this.CheckColumn_CheckStatus,
}
```

and I'm trying to use the renderer to make the check box disabled or invisible:

```
CheckColumn_CheckStatus: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) 
{
   //do something
}
```

if I dont return anything or even return an empty string, the checkbox is not rendered on the UI, but it can still be selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: windowsform? I'm using ext js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return false from a `beforecheckchange` listener E.g.

If you are using the MVC pattern just include it in your controller:

```
'yourgridpanel checkcolumn': {

    beforecheckchange: function(column, index) {
        var user = Ext.getStore('User').first();

        // I was doing this if a user doesn't have permission but
        // if you want to stop all edits you can just return false
        // without the "if" statement
        if (!user || !user.get('edit_permission')) {
            return false; // cancels checkchange event
        }
    }
}
```

If you're not using the MVC pattern you could just attach the listener to the column itself (I'll assume that you want to cancel all check changes in this example):

```
{
    header: 'Select',
    dataIndex: 'indexSelect',
    width: 75,
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    listeners: {
        beforecheckchange: function() {
            return false; // cancels all checkchanges
        }
    }
}, {
    // another column definition, etc...
}
```

Comment: amazing. Thanks very much. Can you check this other problem which I'm also facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674350/extjs-actioncolumn-renderer-prevents-handler